# Finding the lowest value for $a$ at which $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^a}$ is convergent

Tags: convergence-divergence

So I've noticed that for larger values of $a$ the function below forms a bell curve shape whereas for lower values it diverges, I would like to find an approximation for the lowest value at which this is true:
$$f_a(x)=\frac{(2x)!}{(x!)^a}$$

---

I have thought about using stirling's approximation:
$$n!\approx\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac ne\right)^n$$
which would give me:
$$\frac{(2x)!}{(x!)^a}=\frac{\sqrt{4\pi x}\left(\frac{2x}{e}\right)^x}{\left(2\pi x\right)^{a/2}\left(\frac xe\right)^{ax}}=\sqrt{2}\left(2\pi x\right)^{1-a/2}\left(\frac xe\right)^{x(1-a)}2^x$$
$$=2^{x+(3-a)/2}\pi^{1-a/2}x^{x(1-a)+1-a/2}e^{-x(1-a)}$$
if we break this down we are really looking for the convergence of:
$$x^{x(1-a)+1-a/2}e^{-x(1-a)}$$
Then my thoughts were that the $x^x$ term seems the most important term, so the answer would just be $a\ge1$ but I feel like this is not correct. Does anyone have any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: You missed an exponent. The numerator is $(\frac{2x}{e})^{2x}$.

Comment: What's the a? Natural Number, Integer etc.?

Comment: If $a\le 1$, then $(n!)^a\le n!$, so $\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^a}\ge \frac{(2n)!}{n!}\ge \frac{(2n)\cdot n!}{n!}=2n\to+\infty$

Comment: @beingmathematician $a\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Contestosis thanks, Ill add it now

Comment: We must have $a>2$ since $\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}=\binom{2n}{n}$

Comment: The exponent is also $2x$, not $x$. @HenryLee

Comment: If WolframAlpha is right, the result is probably $2$ (see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+to+infinity&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22AsymptoticLimitCalculator%22%2C+%22limitfunction%22%7D+-%3E%22%282x%29%21%2F%28x%21%29%5E%282.001%29%22&assumption=%7B%22FP%22%2C+%22AsymptoticLimitCalculator%22%2C+%22limit%22%7D+-%3E+%22positive%22)).

Comment: I meant any $a \gt 2$.

Comment: @BillyJoe ah yes, thats perfect thanks

Answer (score 3):

When $a=2$ the quotient is $\binom{2n}{n}$ so it goes to infinity.  Let $a = 2+\alpha$ with $\alpha>0$

The $$\begin{align}
\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^a}&=\frac1{(n!)^\alpha}\binom{2n}{n}\\
&\sim\frac1{(n!)^\alpha}\frac{(2n)^{2n}e^{-2n}\sqrt{4\pi n}}{n^{2n}e^{-2n}2\pi n}\\
&=\frac1{(n!)^\alpha}\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}\\
\end{align}$$
which goes to $0$ as $n\to\infty$  To see this, take the logarithm and recall that $\log n! \sim n\log n$.

So there is a largest $a$, namely $2$, such that the sequence does not converge, but no smallest $a$ such that it does.

Comment: when you say "no smallest $a$ such that it does" if we know the largest $a$ for when it diverges then surely $a>2$ suffices for convergence

Comment: @HenryLee Yes, that's what I proved.  But there is no smallest number for which it converges.  If you claim that $2+\varepsilon$ is the smallest, that's wrong, because it also converges for $2+\varepsilon/2$

Comment: Ah yes I get what you are saying, there is no smallest number after 2 its just any number greater than 2

Answer (score 2):

The value you're looking for is $a = 2$.

Indeed, one has, according to Stirling's formula:

$$
\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^a} \quad \underset{n \to +\infty}{\Large{\sim}} \quad \frac{ \sqrt{2 \pi 2 n} (2n)^{2n} e^{-2n} }{ \left( \sqrt{2 \pi n} (n)^{n} e^{-n} \right)^a } = \sqrt{2} \sqrt{2 \pi}^{1-a} n^{ (2-a)n + \frac{1-a}{2} } e^{(a-2)n} 2^{2n}
$$

which you can rewrite as $C \frac{n^{f(n)}}{K^n}$ with $ C :=  \sqrt{2} \sqrt{2 \pi}^{1-a}$, $K = 4e^{a-2} $ and $f(n) = (2-a)n + \frac{1-a}{2}$.

Then:

- if $a < 2$, one has $\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^a} \underset{n \to +\infty}{\longrightarrow} +\infty$.
- if $a = 2$, the limit is also $+\infty$ because of the term $4^n$
- if $a > 2$, the limit is $0$.

Comment: that makes perfect sense thank you!